# cakephp 3 null parameters in view

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am new to cakephp 3 and i try to learn the framework.So i created a Pagescontroller, an index and display function.I want to pass a string or array to view.But i get null value in view.
Below is my code

```
PagesController index action
public function index(){
    $data = "Hello World";

    $this->set(compact('dataSet','data'));
}

Template/Pages/index.ctp view
<?php debug($dataSet); ?>
```

dataSet output is null in index view.I tried the set function without compact with no luck.I wonder what i am doing wrong.

Comment: How is your solution in any way related to the problem that you've described? With the original route, your action would have never been called in the first place. `dataSet` is `null` in the view template because there is no `dataSet` variable in your controller, modifying routes will not change that fact.

Comment: Solutions do not belong in the question, please answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: Any help to improve the question is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this in routes.php

```
 $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index','index']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo do not need `dataSet` in set compact.

The best way to learn cakePhp framework is to read tutorial and use cake bake. In this tutorial you have a lot of basic examples -> https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html#

Your code should look like:

```
PagesController index action
public function index(){
  $myData = 'My data';
  $this->set(compact('myData'));
}

Template/Pages/index.ctp view
<?php debug($myData); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

In view

```
<?php debug($data); ?>
```

Comment: Than use    $this->set('data',$data);   in the controller.